# FIle upload with chunks: avoid saving it twice

Tags: django, file-upload, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I use a custom function to upload a file splitting it in chunks, as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files).
My problem is that calling `save()` after `handle_uploaded_file()` uploads my file twice, one into "MEDIA_URL/my_path" dir and one into "MEDIA_URL".
But I would like to have only one upload, the one with chunks.
It is possible to force `save()` to make 'chunked' upload?
Or should I use different approaches?
Thank you.

- models.py

  ```
  class ShapeFile(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      srid = models.ForeignKey(SpatialRefSys)
      user = models.ForeignKey(User)
      color_table = models.ForeignKey(ColorTable)
      file = models.FileField(upload_to="my_path")
      class Meta:
          unique_together = ('name', 'user')
  ```
- forms.py

  ```
  class UploadForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
          model = ShapeFile
          fields = ('name','user','srid','file','color_table')
          widgets = {'srid': TextInput(),
                     'user': HiddenInput()
  ```
- views.py

  ```
  def handle_uploaded_file(fileName, filePath):
      with open(filePath, 'wb+') as destination:
          for chunk in fileName.chunks():
              destination.write(chunk)

  @login_required
  def shapeIng(request):
      if request.method == 'POST':
          form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
          if form.is_valid():
              req = request.POST

              # Split uploaded file into chunks
              fileName = request.FILES['file']
              filePath = ShapeFile(file=fileName).file.path
              handle_uploaded_file(fileName, filePath)

              form.save()

              messages.success(request, 'Shapefile upload succesful!')
              return redirect('shapeCreated')
          else:
              messages.error(request, 'Something went wrong uploading Shapefile.')
      else: # request.method == 'GET'
          form = UploadForm(initial={'user': request.user})
      return render_to_response('my_app/base_shapeIngestion.html',
                                {'form': form},
                                context_instance=RequestContext(request))
  ```

Comment: Try not passing the `request.FILES` to the `UploadForm`. Use it only for the handler.

Comment: If I do that, the `is_valid()` method is not satisfied and I correctly get "This field is required" message on the page, even if I choose a field to upload.

Answer (score 0):

change your view function to this:

```
def testupload2(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file_name=request.FILES['file']
    form = SomeForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        dest_file = open('C:/prototype/upload/'+ str(file_name), 'wb+')
        path = 'C:/prototype/upload/'+ str(file_name)
        for chunk in  request.FILES['file'].chunks():
            dest_file.write(chunk)
        dest_file.close()

    t = get_template("testupload2.html")

    lst = os.listdir('C:/downloads/prototype/prototype/upload/')

    html = t.render(Context({'MEDIA_URL':'http://127.0.0.1:8000/site_media/'}))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: What the purpose of `to_json` and `arr` variables? How to save the other 4 elements of my form if do not use `form.save()`? Why to use `HttpResponse`?

Comment: @caneta i was using these two for some other functionality in my project while writing the answer i forgot to remove them

Comment: Ok...and what about the other elements to save from the form?